# What data do I need to store for OAuth2 server-to-server communication?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, thephpleague

## Background

My application is getting data from many different sources (APIs) and aggregating across them. So the user logs via OAuth2 into the source once and afterward I continuously make calls to the source.

I am using `thephpleague/oauth2-client` to connect to different services, I also use provider packages build on top to connect to different websites. I have absolutely no issue there.

Once I authenticate I get an `League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken` instance.

## Current situation

Right now for storage, I do a `json_encode` on the `AccessToken` instance and store the resulting unstructured `string`. To load it, I `json_decode` and create a new instance via the constructor. Not really interesting.

## The question

If I wanted to store the access token(the OAuth response in general) a structured way, what data would I need? What do I need to persist for server-to-server communication? The specific items and their types? I am trying to figure out the data model for storing many different providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#Sources
The sources for the answer are 2 fold:

1. **The RFC**: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1 - Given the RFC the fields are:

- `access_token` - a REQUIRED value of pseudotype `string`
- `token_type` - a REQUIRED value of pseudotype `string`
- `expires_in` - a recommended value of pseudotype `int`
- `refresh_token` - an optional value of pseudotype `string`
- `scope` - an optional value of pseudotype `string` in case of different granted scope from the scope asked in the request

The RFC stipulates that `The client MUST ignore unrecognized value names in the response.`, however in the example, they provide in this section, they include a previously undefined `value name`.

2. **The library mentioned**: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/master/src/Token/AccessToken.php#L59 - Given the constructor:

- `access_token` - a REQUIRED value of pseudotype `string`
- `resource_owner_id` - a optional value of pseudotype `string`
- `refresh_token` - an optional value of pseudotype `string`
- `expires_in` - a optional value of pseudotype `int` with fallback to `expires` as a value of pseudotype `int`

Whatever else is passed into the constructor is treated as extra data.

#Implications

- `access_token` and `refresh_token` should be stored, both as a string with the caveat that `refresh_token` can be null
- `token_type` is implied in the library used and is not necessary in this case, but might be for some other people.
- `expires_in` should be stored as some representation of a point in time.
- `resource_owner_id` is a custom value name that your library can work with. Store it as a string if you want to use it.
- `scope` could be useful to store if your application tests for scope authorization before an API request. Store it as string.
- anything else is a custom value and should be treated as such. There is really low chance of overlap in value names between different providers. can be stored as an array of string.